# Wordpress functions.php does not affect the theme menus

Tags: menus, navigation

I am trying to customize my pre bought theme. What i try is, to have different menus for each page without using a plugin. Original theme has a function about navigation which uses walker class. here is the file in the original.entrepreneur theme. http://pastebin.com/TeT8hi7z.

I use Entrepreneur Child Theme. I want to use primary navigation in home page and turkish navigation in turkish flag. I added functions.php and I added the code below:

```
if (is_page('AOE Home')){
    wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'Primary Navigation' ));
    } elseif (is_page('turkish')) {
        echo "text";
    wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'Turkish Navigation' ));
}
```

But navigation elements stays same. Can you help me to solve my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with adding this code into **header.php**, where menu usually appears. In functions.php you can declare custom menus, but you are **calling** them in header.php or wherever you want menus to appear.

Function **register_nav_menus()** declares menus and should go into functions.php,  while **wp_nav_menu()** outputs menus you declared anywhere on the page (so not inside functions.php).

Comment: I will try that solution; but site has stuck.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Site was not opening. I tried it but still no solution. Your answer makes logic. But I am too tired to try more. Tomorrow I'll let you know .

Comment: With some debugging you will get there, now that you know how should it go :)